# MySQL join getting duplicate result

Tags: php, mysql

I have to display student 'john' information.

**John's Information Table - Student**

```
id  | Roll | name  | class  | year 
==================================
1   |    1 | john  |     7  | 2
```

**John's Mark Table - Mark**

```
id  |   std_id  |   sub_id  |   th  |   pr
===========================================
1   |   1       |   1       |   60  |   20
2   |   1       |   2       |   55  |   18
```

**John's Education Year Table - Year**

```
id  |   title
=============
1   |   2017
2   |   2018
```

**John's Class Table - Class**

```
id  |   title
=============
7   |   Seven
8   |   Eight
```

**John's Subject Table - Subject**

```
id  |   title
=============
1   |   Science
2   |   Math
```

Now my requirement is as follow

```
Name: John
Class: Seven
Year: 2018
Science: 60 (TH)
Math: 55 (TH)
```

But, here is getting duplicate results. I get john's information repetitively counting total rows in `mark` table of this student.

```
Name: John
Class: Seven
Year: 2018
Science: 60 (TH)

Name: John
Class: Seven
Year: 2018
Math: 55 (TH)
```

I have tried using `GROUP BY` to std.id, to prevent duplicate but it shows only first row of mark table. In here, only science mark had showed.

```
$result=$con->prepare(
    "SELECT
        student.id, student.en_name AS name, student.class, 
        class.title AS class, 
        year.title AS year,
        subject.title AS sub,

        mark.sub_id,
        mark.th,
        mark.pr

        FROM student

        JOIN year ON year.id = student.year 
        JOIN class ON class.id = student.class 
        JOIN mark ON mark.std_id = student.id
        INNER JOIN subject ON subject.id = mark.sub_id
        WHERE student.id=:id;"
) or die($con->error);

    $result->bindParam(':id',$_POST['std']);
    $result->execute();
    while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $name=$row['name'];
        $class=$row['class'];
        $sub=$row['sub'];
        $year=$row['year'];
        $th=$row['th'];
        $pr=$row['pr']; echo" 
        <article id='blg_half'>
            <article class='left'>
                Name: $name<br/>
                Class: $class<br/>
                Year: $year<br/>
                $sub : $th(th)
            </article>
        </article>";
    }
```

Comment: What is your expected output?  Why do you think you need to use `GROUP BY` here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I am trying to fetch all marks of `student.id`. `join` displays all `rows` of this `id`, but it is repeating same student counting values in mark. So to prevent repeat I use `GROUP BY`, group by stops to prevent but shows only first row of mark table, it has to display all mark.

Comment: You should show us your expected output, so that we don't have to guess at what you actually want.

Comment: You don't need to get students all subject marks with Inner join or group by just get student data and then get marks table data, inner joint just create duplicate information for each row

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, so wait, let me clarify this

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I've edited my question, now it would be clear, Please see updated post

Answer (score 0):

Try with inner join, no need to group by according to your question

```
    SELECT
        student.roll, student.name, student.address, student.img, student.class, student.section,
        class.title AS class, 
        section.title AS section, 
        year.title AS year,
        mark.id, mark.th, mark.pr
        FROM student 
        inner JOIN year ON year.id = student.year 
        inner class ON class.id = student.class 
        inner JOIN section ON section.id = student.section
        inner JOIN mark ON mark.std_id = student.id
group by student.roll, student.name, student.address, student.img, student.class, student.section,
        class.title AS class, 
        section.title AS section, 
        year.title AS year,
        mark.id, mark.th, mark.pr
```

Comment: `inner join` works, but it is repeating same student counting values in `mark` table. So to prevent repeat I use `GROUP BY`, group by stops to repeat but shows only first row of mark table, it has to display all mark without repeating.

Comment: modify my query, then use all fields of selection list in group by

Comment: tried but doesn't work. please see my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

According to your updated question, you actually need GROUP_CONCAT to produce the result:

```
SELECT
    student.id, 
    student.roll, student.name, student.address, student.img, 
    class.title AS class,
    subject.title AS sub,
    `year`.title AS yr,
    GROUP_CONCAT(mark.th) AS th,
    GROUP_CONCAT(mark.pr) AS pr
FROM student 
JOIN `year` ON `year`.id = student.`year` 
JOIN class ON class.id = student.class 
LEFT JOIN mark ON mark.std_id = student.id
LEFT JOIN subject ON subject.id = mark.sub_id
WHERE student.id = :id 
GROUP BY student.id
```

MySQL should be ok with above SQL, however standard SQL should group by all fields in SELECT except GROUP_CONCAT()

Also you cannot group by ... when select mark.id -- which make no sense

Comment: just use inner joining is `repeating` same student `counting rows` in mark. For example student `John` has 3 rows in mark table. I want to show as John->60, 55, 73 (because `std.id` is same) but here I am getting John->60, John->55, John->73

Answer (score 0):

Try to Left Join with mark table :

```
SELECT 
student.roll, student.name, student.address, student.img, student.class, student.section,
class.title AS class, 
section.title AS section, 
year.title AS year,
mark.id, mark.th, mark.pr
FROM mark 
LEFT JOIN student ON student.id = mark.std_id   
LEFT JOIN year ON year.id = student.year 
LEFT JOIN class ON class.id = student.class 
LEFT JOIN section ON section.id = student.section
WHERE mark.std_id =:id
```

Comment: I tried `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN`, just use joining is repeating same student counting rows in mark. For example student John has 3 rows in mark table. I want to show as John->60, 55, 73 (because std.id is same) but here I am getting John->60, John->55, John->73

Comment: Can you share the expected result in table?

Comment: @GovindSamrrow, Please see updated post, now it should be clear.

Comment: @AnandHmt it's not possible with single query, you need to get it with two different queries

Comment: Yes with subquery or separate query and the merge the result of both queries

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
        student.id, student.name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(subject.title,year.title,class.title,mark.th)) as Marks 
        FROM student
        LEFT JOIN year ON year.id = student.year 
        LEFT JOIN class ON class.id = student.class 
        LEFT JOIN mark ON mark.std_id = student.id
        LEFT JOIN subject ON subject.id = mark.sub_id
        WHERE student.id=:id
        GROUP BY student.id
```